# Guess the other shape

Tags: pattern, visual

Each solid shape is somehow related to the shape below it.

Find this relationship and the correct shape for the last one.

[image]

Edit: simplified second shape from left to a polygon

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> C

Explanation

> Read the circles/bars from front to back based on the way they overlap each other, they form binary numbers.
> For example, the circles/bars represent, from left to right: 10, 110, 11, 101, 011, 00.
> This matches the number of points (or convex corners) on the shape above.  (from the third shape we can tell that concave corners are to be ignored)
> The last shape has 5 points, so we want 101, which is C.

Excellent puzzle!

Comment: Well done! It should be more fun if there was another 1,0,1 option that was not in right order.

Comment: Could you explain the number of points part?

Comment: @Tom Hart: If the shape were to hit you in the face, which parts would poke your eye out?  Those are the points.  I edited to call them convex corners, if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

by Elimination i choose

> C.

All the patterns with a triangle/sharp shape have 2 rods.

the last pattern has a triangle shape too. and there is only one answer with 2 rods.

Comment: That was not the answer I have expected. Also no description for the relationship. so the picture is now edited (the triangle from second shape from left is removed) thanks

Answer (score 2):

An alternate answer would be:

> B

Following the logic that:

> IFF the (silhouet of the) lower shape has rotational symmetry, the upper shape has rotational symmetry (and vice versa)

Comment: what do you mean by rotational symmetry? do you mean the same shape if rotate it 180 degrees?

Comment: @Rafe In general less than 360 (in these cases it would be either 180 or 120)

Comment: hmmm... that's interesting. what about the circle? the shape below it has not rotational symmetry!

Comment: @Rafe That is why I only looked at the silhouette.

Comment: Oh... That's right! :-)

Answer (score 1):

> C

Since by eliminating the other options.

> Since its doesn't have a round geometry whatsoever, A,D eliminated.
>  B resembles to the 1st figure, therefore C would be a fair assumption.